# como puedo solucionar este error al instalar builtdozer

Tags: python

El comando.

```
pip install --upgrade buildozer
```

El error que me devuelve es siempre el mismo.

> root@android-HP-ProBook-6550b:/home/android# pip install buildozer
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in
>   from pip import main ImportError: cannot import name main

Porque no me deja instalar buildozer, alguna forma posible de solucionarlo?

Comment: Prueba de esta manera `pip install --upgrade buildozer`

Comment: Por la traza no creo que el error sea de Buidozer, ¿Puedes instalar otros paquetes vía pip? Parece como si tuvieras el paquete pip roto (por una mala actualización del mismo por ejemplo), trata de reinstalarlo.

Comment: el error me da al instalarlo con ese comando que citaron pip install --upgrade buildozer intente pero que me recomiendas reinstalar

Comment: Sergio ¿que ocurre si tratas de hacer `pip install --upgrade pip`? Si se confirma que es problema de pip, me refiero a reinstalar el paquete, no se que distro usas pero me refiero a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917534/pip-broken-on-ubuntu-14-4-after-package-upgrade/28919613#28919613, aunque hay distintas formas.

Comment: ya intente con un upgrade y sigue retornado el error el buildozer

Answer (score 0):

La versión de pip 10.0.0 tiene ese problema. Por favor, podrías asegurarte que no sea un problema con pip, simplemente haciendo:

```
$ pip -V
```

Si sigues obteniendo el mismo resultado, puedes apoyarte con las respuestas de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881448/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-after-upgrading-tp-pip-10-0-0-for-python-ve/50029319#50029319

A mi me funcionó modificar el archivo donde pip se encuentra y después actualizar a la versión 10.0.1; con la que hasta el momento no he tenido problemas.

Comment: sigue devolviendo el error.... Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-drIGjM/buildozer/